# Can't understand SocketJS Error

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, symfony, websocket

I'm currently developping a project with a Symfony API (version 3 with PHP 7.1) and a NodeJS Client with Angular 4.
Within the local environment, everything is working well, but when I try to deploy on the production server, I get the error "WDS Disconnected" and a connection error with sockjs.
I don't know where the error comes from.

Have you ever encountered this kind of error and have you got an idea on how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot.

[caption of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eGGo.png)

Comment: Is it too difficult for you to google for `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`?

Comment: no, I already did it but the solutions I found did not help me at all...